# How to convert pandas DataFrame to specific annotated csv-like format (described inside)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert this `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'world'], [4, 'hello']],
    columns=['A', 'B'],
)
```

to this string:

```
'A=1,B=world\nA=4,B=hello'
```

Where each row in separated by a `\n` and each column is added before each value as `col_name=col_value`

**What I tried**

I am generally quite lost as to how to approach this in a non-looping and time-sensible way.

One thing I thought was to use `df.to_csv()` and then amend this, but that seems to get messy quickly.

Another approach I though was to convert all to string and add to each column the `col_name=` and then do `.to_csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert values to list of dicts by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), for each dictionary join columns with values by `f-string`s and join by `,`, last join values by `//n`:

```
a = '\\n'.join(','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in x.items()) 
                                   for x in df.to_dict(orient='records'))
print (a)
A=1,B=world\nA=4,B=hello
```

Comment: Is it possible to an add `if` `else` in the generator expression. I succeeded to add an `if` but failed on the `else` so was wonder whether possible at all?

Comment: @Newskooler Change `f'{k}={v}'` to `f'{k}={v}' if k =='A' else f'{k}==={v}'` is possible solution for if else in generator.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your DataFrame's to element to str using `df.astype`, then we need to add `'='` before every element. Then join each with delim `','` and all of them with delim `'\\n'`.

```
vals = '=' + df.astype(str).values
cols = df.columns.values
vals = cols[None, :] + vals
vals = np.apply_along_axis(','.join, 1, vals)

out = '\\n'.join(vals)
# A=1,B=world\nA=4,B=hello
```

#### Details

```
vals = '=' + df.astype(str).values
# array([['=1', '=world'],
#        ['=4', '=hello']], dtype=object)

cols = df.columns.values
vals = cols[None, :] + vals
# array([['A=1', 'B=world'],
#        ['A=4', 'B=hello']], dtype=object)

vals = np.apply_along_axis(','.join, 1, vals)
# array(['A=1,B=world', 'A=4,B=hello'], dtype='<U11')

out = '\\n'.join(vals)
# A=1,B=world\nA=4,B=hello
```